# Angular Material Design virtual repeat filter data

Tags: angularjs, filter, material-design, infinite-scroll

i'm using angular-material 0.11.2 and trying to make something with virtual repeat.

the html part of the code is

```
<div layout="row" flex class="md-padding" style="padding-bottom:0;">
    <md-input-container>
        <div layout="row">
            <div layout="column">
                <label>Arama</label>
                <input ng-model="searchCriteria" style="width:300px !important;" type="text">
            </div>
            <div layout="column" flex>
                <div layout="row">
                   <md-checkbox class="md-primary" ng-model="filterLocal" aria-label="Local" ng-change="">
                      Merkez Birimler
                   </md-checkbox>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                        
    </md-input-container>
</div>
<md-content class="md-padding divInfiniteScroll" layout="column">
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="distributionItemInfiniteScrollContainer" flex>
        <div md-virtual-repeat="item in testData" md-on-demand class="repeated-item" flex>
            {{item.Id}}
        </div>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
</md-content>
```

and the javascript part is;

```
$scope.testData = {
    numLoaded_: 0,
    toLoad_: 0,
    items: [],
    // Required.
    getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
        if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
            this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
            return null;
        }
        return this.items[index];
    },
    // Required.
    // For infinite scroll behavior, we always return a slightly higher
    // number than the previously loaded items.
    getLength: function() {
        return this.numLoaded_ + 10;
    },
    fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {
        if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
            this.toLoad_ += 10;

            var searchObject= {};
            searchObject.SearchCriteria = $scope.searchCriteria;
            searchObject.Local = $scope.filterLocal;

            var that = this;
            $myService.search(searchObject, index).then(function complete(data) {
                that.items = that.items.concat(data);
                that.numLoaded_ = that.toLoad_;
            });
        }

    }
};
```

I want to filter the virtual scroll data with the checkboxes status and the data from text element. For example, initially virtual-repeat has 1000 rows, include locals and remotes, if i check the checkboxes, gets only locals from services (remote db), if uncheck gets both. Or write something in input, again data must be changed. But i don't have any idea for to do it. The documentation does not contain any information about this too, have any idea? Please provide some information to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, in fetchMoreItems_ function, i wrote the code below to the service call complete method's first line and then, the scroll stops when the data finish.

```
if (!data || data.length == 0) {
   return false;
}
```